Holomorphic non vanishing modular forms without regularity at infinity
Let $\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{H})^\times$ be the multiplicative group of holomorphic functions on the Poincaré half-plane $\mathcal{H}$ that do not vanish there.
Let $j(g,z)=(cz+d)$ and $gz=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ when $g$ is the matrix $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and $z\in\mathcal{H}$.
For which values of $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k\neq 0$, are there functions $a\in\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{H})^\times$ such that,
$$
\forall g\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\quad\forall z\in\mathcal{H}\quad a(gz)=j(g,z)^ka(z). 
$$
Necessarily, $k$ is even and $a$ is periodic with period $1$, so I can talk about regularity at infinity.
If I add a condition of meromorphy at infinity, the function $a$ is necessarily a modular function of weight $k$, the formula $k/12$ implies that the order of $f$ at infinity is $k/12$ and $k$ must be a multiple of $12$: in this case, $\Delta^{k/12}$ is suitable where $\Delta$ is the unique weight $12$ primitive form with level $1$.
So let's write $k=12q+r$ with $r\in\{2,4,6,8,10\}$. If there exists a function $a$ as a solution, then the function $a/\Delta^q$, which is an element of $\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{H})^\times$, is a solution to the problem by replacing $k$ with $r$.
Therefore, the question reduces to the following :
For $k\in\{2,4,6,8,10\}$, does it exist holomorphic functions $a$ that do not vanish on $\mathcal{H}$ (and are necessarily non-meromorphic at infinity) such that
$$
\forall g\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\quad\forall z\in\mathcal{H}\quad a(gz)=j(g,z)^ka(z) ?
$$

What is $ż$ in $gz=(aż+b)/(cz+d)$? Was it meant just to be $z$?

Strange dot on the z indeed.
Yes, gz=(az+b)/(cz+d).
I edited my post to make the correction. Thanks.

Note: this has since been cross-posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/470412/6518

I think it makes sense to crosspost this to MO. I also appreciate that you waited a week before crossposting --- that helps prevent duplication of effort. But it is best if you indicate yourself that you're crossposting.

Thanks. Crossposting is like asking a question in two different coffee rooms (and the fact is that I do not really know who is where) and I need time to go from one to another. But, I agree, next time I do that, I will make it explicit.

No, there are no such functions for weights $k \not\equiv 0 \bmod 12$.
Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathcal{H}$ invariant under $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ but with no conditions at $\infty$.
Lemma: $f$ vanishes at $z = i$ with even order and vanishes at $z = \rho = e^{2 \pi i/6}$ to order divisible by three.
Proof: This follows because $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ has elements of projective order $2$ and $3$ respectively which fix these points. There are many
ways to argue but here is a very elementary version. Note that $f(\tau) = f(-1/\tau)$. Suppose that the power series development of $f(i+z)$ is given by $a z^{r} + \ldots$ which converges for small enough $z$ since everything is holomorphic. With $\tau = i + z$ we have
$$a z^r + O(z^{r+1}) = f(i + z) = f(\tau) = f(-1/\tau)
= f\left(\frac{-1}{i + z}\right) = f\left(i - z + i z^2 + \ldots\right) = a (-z + i z^2 + \ldots)^r  + O(z^{r+1}) = a (-1)^r z^r + + O(z^{r+1}),$$
and thus $(-1)^r = 1$ and $r$ is even. The same argument with $\tau \rightarrow -1/\tau$ replaced by the order three map $\tau \rightarrow 1-1/\tau$ gives the result for $\rho$.
Returning to your question. Suppose $a$ is any function of your desired kind in even weight $k \ge 4$. Then $E_{k}/a$ is holomorphic on $\mathcal{H}$ and invariant under $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. (Here $E_k$ could be any classical modular form of weight $k$.) The lemma shows that $E_{k}/a$ vanishes to even order at $i$ and to order divisible by three at $\rho$. But since $a$ is non-vanishing everywhere the same applies to $E_{k}$ itself. But then the weight formula
$$\frac{k}{12} = v_{\infty} + \frac{v_i}{2} + \frac{v_{\rho}}{3} + v_{\mathrm{else}}$$
says that the weight of $E_{k}$ is a multiple of $12$, so $k \equiv 0 \bmod 12$.
(This applies also in weight $k=2$ and negative weights by a simple reduction, for example after multiplying by a sufficiently large power of $\Delta$.)

Many thanks! However, how do you apply the weight formula to $E_k/a$ without making any assumption on the behavior of $a$ at $\infty$?

You're right. Thank you very much
